# Given a string, how to check if the first few characters == another string? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have an array of char, that I can convert to a string if needed.

The string can be a whole sentence long, but I only care about the first 6 characters of the string, as they would be the command action for my program (add/remove/delete etc).

I was wondering, how would I go about doing this? Either checking the first few chars, or even better just evaluating the first word in an array of char or string.

Comment: You probably want to look into either the substr () method to extract the first 6 characters, or the compare () method if you want to do the comparison in-place.

Comment: `std::strncmp` is an option

Comment: "*or even better just evaluating the first word*" - create a `std::istreamstream` from the string, use `operator>>` to extract the first word (however long it happens to be) into a `std::string`, and then use `operator==` to test its value as needed

Comment: The question is confusing. Do you want the first 6 characters or the first word?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you want to compare s1 == s2(0, 10), which means the first ten characters of string *s2*, use **substr()** may work it through, like this :

```
s1 == s2.substr(0, 10);
```

in which, **s2.substr(pos, n)** mean the continuous *n* characters begin with the *pos-th* position of string *s2*.

Another funtion is also goot to use :

```
s1.compare(pos1, n1, s2);
```

menas: compare the *n1* characters begin from pos1 position of string s1, to string 2. You can checkout this funtion and its overloaded other five funtions.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in-place, just use `std::strncmp()`.  For example:

```
bool first_n_equal(const char *lhs, const char *rhs, size_t n) {
    return (std::strncmp(lhs, rhs, n) == 0);
}
```

Note that `strncmp` returns 0 if the two strings are equal, and will only compare up to `n` characters.  To pick `n` you can hardcode 6, or loop over your string and check for where the first word ends. For example,

```
size_t size_of_first_word(const char *str) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0'; i++) {}
    return i;
}
```

This function loops over the string until it hits a space or a null terminator (end of string). Then, to actually check your string for a command:

```
size_t input_len = size_of_first_word(input_string);
size_t command_len = size_of_first_word(command_string);
size_t check_len = std::min(input_len, command_len);
bool is_same = first_n_equal(input_string, command_string, check_len);
```

I intentionally made this verbose to make it easier to understand, so you can absolutely make this code smaller.  You could also use `std::string` but it's not actually necessary.